# X server crashes on startup with error message "No V_BIOS found". How can I fix this?

Tags: debian, xorg, x-server

I am running Debian with an ATI Radeon E6760 graphics card and the amd-catalyst-13.12 driver installed.
Everything worked fine for a long time.
I started the computer with a scientific linux live usb boot on Friday and left it running over the weekend. 
When I returned to it on Monday the screen was blank.
Rebooting with the usual debian setup, the problem remains.
I can ssh into the machine and when I try to launch the X server, I get the following output.

```
root@anita2:/home/anita# X&
[1] 1684
root@anita2:/home/anita# 
X.Org X Server 1.7.7
Release Date: 2010-05-04
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.0.0-1-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux anita2 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 25 00:26:11 UTC 2013 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/anita2-root ro quiet
Build Date: 29 October 2011  06:58:14PM
xorg-server 2:1.7.7-14 (Julien Cristau <jcristau@debian.org>) 
Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jun 10 19:07:49 2014
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) fglrx(0): No V_BIOS found
(EE) fglrx(0): Failed to obtain VBIOS from Kernel!
(EE) fglrx(0): No V_BIOS found
(EE) fglrx(0): DAL initialization failed!
(EE) fglrx(0): Display Infrastructure Failed
(EE) fglrx(0): PreInit failed

Message from syslogd@anita2 at Jun 10 19:07:50 ...
 kernel:[ 1356.269414] Oops: 0000 [#3] SMP 

Message from syslogd@anita2 at Jun 10 19:07:50 ...
 kernel:[ 1356.269417] last sysfs file: /sys/module/fglrx/initstate

Message from syslogd@anita2 at Jun 10 19:07:50 ...
 kernel:[ 1356.269582] Stack:

Message from syslogd@anita2 at Jun 10 19:07:50 ...
 kernel:[ 1356.269597] Call Trace:

Message from syslogd@anita2 at Jun 10 19:07:50 ...
 kernel:[ 1356.270129] Code: 00 00 48 89 4c 24 38 48 8b 97 80 2a 00 00 48 89 54 24 30 48 8b 54 24 38 48 8b 6a 08 48 39 c5 74 32 49 89 c6 66 66 66 90 66 66 90 <8b> 45 34 4c 8b 6d 08 41 85 c7 74 14 85 db 0f 85 01 01 00 00 a8 

Message from syslogd@anita2 at Jun 10 19:07:50 ...
 kernel:[ 1356.270249] CR2: 0000000000000034

[1]+  Killed                  X
```

My xorg conf file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
        Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:4:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
        Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

and xorg log:

```
X.Org X Server 1.7.7
Release Date: 2010-05-04
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.0.0-1-amd64 x86_64 Debian
Current Operating System: Linux anita2 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 25 00:26:11 UTC 2013 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-2.6.32-5-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/anita2-root ro quiet
Build Date: 29 October 2011  06:58:14PM
xorg-server 2:1.7.7-14 (Julien Cristau <jcristau@debian.org>) 
Current version of pixman: 0.16.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Jun 10 19:07:49 2014
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) ServerLayout "aticonfig Layout"
(**) |-->Screen "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" (0)
(**) |   |-->Monitor "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
(**) |   |-->Device "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
(==) Automatically adding devices
(==) Automatically enabling devices
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
        Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
        Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
        Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1" does not exist.
        Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
        Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
        Entry deleted from font path.
(WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType".
        Entry deleted from font path.
        (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType").
(==) FontPath set to:
        /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
        built-ins
(==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
(II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
        If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
(II) Loader magic: 0x7c8a40
(II) Module ABI versions:
        X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
        X.Org Video Driver: 6.0
        X.Org XInput driver : 7.0
        X.Org Server Extension : 2.0
(--) using VT number 7

(--) PCI:*(0:4:0:0) 1002:6743:0000:0000 ATI Technologies Inc rev 0, Mem @ 0xe8000000/134217728, 0xf7920000/131072, I/O @ 0x0000d000/256, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
(WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
(II) "extmod" will be loaded by default.
(II) "dbe" will be loaded by default.
(II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
(II) "record" will be loaded by default.
(II) "dri" will be loaded by default.
(II) "dri2" will be loaded by default.
(II) LoadModule: "extmod"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
(II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.7.7, module version = 1.0.0
        Module class: X.Org Server Extension
        ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension SELinux
(II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
(II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
(II) Loading extension DPMS
(II) Loading extension XVideo
(II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
(II) Loading extension X-Resource
(II) LoadModule: "dbe"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
(II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.7.7, module version = 1.0.0
        Module class: X.Org Server Extension
        ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
(II) LoadModule: "glx"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
(II) Module glx: vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc."
        compiled for 6.9.0, module version = 1.0.0
(II) Loading extension GLX
(II) LoadModule: "record"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
(II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.7.7, module version = 1.13.0
        Module class: X.Org Server Extension
        ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension RECORD
(II) LoadModule: "dri"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
(II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.7.7, module version = 1.0.0
        ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
(II) LoadModule: "dri2"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
(II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.7.7, module version = 1.1.0
        ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 2.0
(II) Loading extension DRI2
(II) LoadModule: "fglrx"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fglrx_drv.so
(II) Module fglrx: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
        compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 13.25.5
        Module class: X.Org Video Driver
(II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
(II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
(II) Module fglrxdrm: vendor="FireGL - AMD Technologies Inc."
        compiled for 1.4.99.906, module version = 13.25.5
(II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Version Identifier:13.25.5
(II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Release Identifier: 13.251                               
(II) AMD Proprietary Linux Driver Build Date: Dec  6 2013 15:19:03
(II) Primary Device is: PCI 04@00:00:0
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for fglrx
(II) Loading PCS database from /etc/ati/amdpcsdb /etc/ati/amdpcsdb.default
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:4:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 9, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 9
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:4:0:0
(--) Chipset Supported AMD Graphics Processor (0x6743) found
(II) fglrx(0): pEnt->device->identifier=0xdc0180
(II) fglrx(0): === [xdl_x750_atiddxPreInit] === begin
(II) Loading sub module "vgahw"
(II) LoadModule: "vgahw"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvgahw.so
(II) Module vgahw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.7.7, module version = 0.1.0
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 6.0
(**) fglrx(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
(II) fglrx(0): Pixel depth = 24 bits stored in 4 bytes (32 bpp pixmaps)
(==) fglrx(0): Default visual is TrueColor
(**) fglrx(0): Option "DPMS" "true"
(==) fglrx(0): RGB weight 888
(II) fglrx(0): Using 8 bits per RGB 
(==) fglrx(0): Buffer Tiling is ON
(II) Loading sub module "fglrxdrm"
(II) LoadModule: "fglrxdrm"
(II) Reloading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/linux/libfglrxdrm.so
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 252
ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:4:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 11, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 11
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:4:0:0
(**) fglrx(0): NoAccel = NO
(**) fglrx(0): AMD 2D Acceleration Architecture enabled
(--) fglrx(0): Chipset: "AMD Radeon E6760" (Chipset = 0x6743)
(--) fglrx(0): (PciSubVendor = 0x0000, PciSubDevice = 0x0000)
(==) fglrx(0): board vendor info: third party graphics adapter - NOT original AMD
(--) fglrx(0): Linear framebuffer (phys) at 0xe8000000
(--) fglrx(0): MMIO registers at 0xf7920000
(--) fglrx(0): I/O port at 0x0000d000
(==) fglrx(0): ROM-BIOS at 0x000c0000
(II) fglrx(0): AC Adapter is used
(EE) fglrx(0): No V_BIOS found
(EE) fglrx(0): Failed to obtain VBIOS from Kernel!
(II) Loading sub module "vbe"
(II) LoadModule: "vbe"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
(II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.7.7, module version = 1.1.0
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 6.0
(II) Loading sub module "int10"
(II) LoadModule: "int10"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
(II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.7.7, module version = 1.0.0
        ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 6.0
(II) fglrx(0): initializing int10
(EE) fglrx(0): No V_BIOS found
(WW) fglrx(0): GetVBEMode failed
(--) fglrx(0): Video RAM: 0 kByte, Type: 
(II) fglrx(0): PCIE card detected
(--) fglrx(0): Using per-process page tables (PPPT) as GART.
(WW) fglrx(0): board is an unknown third party board, chipset is supported
(II) fglrx(0): [FB] MC range(MCFBBase = 0x0, MCFBSize = 0x0)
(II) fglrx(0): RandR 1.2 support is enabled!
(II) fglrx(0): RandR 1.2 rotation support is enabled!
(==) fglrx(0): Center Mode is disabled 
(II) Loading sub module "fb"
(II) LoadModule: "fb"
(II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
(II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
        compiled for 1.7.7, module version = 1.0.0
        ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
(II) Loading sub module "ddc"
(II) LoadModule: "ddc"
(II) Module "ddc" already built-in
(EE) fglrx(0): DAL initialization failed!
(EE) fglrx(0): Display Infrastructure Failed
(EE) fglrx(0): PreInit failed
(II) fglrx(0): === [xdl_x750_atiddxPreInit] === end
```

I notice that BIOS @ 0x????????/131072 in the xorg log probably isn't good. I don't know what could have caused this or how to do anything about it. Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As a hunch, it sounds like you overwrote your kernel with the one from SL Linux.  SL Linux's kernel doesn't contain your Video Cards BIOS Copy.

[SL Linux 6](http://www.scientificlinux.org/news/sl6.4-live) is a Fedora Variant, as of [Fedora 19, the stable kernel is 3.14](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Kernel).  Your BOOT command line indicates you are using kernel 2.6.  Try upgrading your kernel to the [current debian release](http://packages.qa.debian.org/l/linux.html), which is also 3.14, then rebuild the catalyst drivers and XOrg Server.